# Anonymous Block Query for Related Column from a Custom Object

Tags: execute-anonymous

I am trying to display firstname from contact but am getting this:

> Line: 1, Column: 36 id, (select id , firstname from contact) from
>   Company_Contact_Relation__c ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:40 Didn't
>   understand relationship 'contact' in FROM part of query call. If you
>   are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the
>   '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL
>   or the describe call for the appropriate names.

If I omit the subquery I get the contact id but I want to be able to access the columns in contact.

```
Company_Contact_Relation__c ccr  = [Select id, (select id , firstname from contact) from Company_Contact_Relation__c limit 1];

system.debug(JSON.serializepretty(ccr));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to acquire the answer from another resource but wanted to provide the answer in case anyone else searches for this question.  The key was to change add the __r to the object Contact aka `Contact__r.<ColumnName>` aka `FirstName`.

```
List<Company_Contact_Relation__c> lstCompanyContactRelation = [Select id, name, Contact__c, ***Contact__r.FirstName*** from Company_Contact_Relation__c limit 1];
system.debug(JSON.serializepretty(lstCompanyContactRelation));
```

Answer (score 2):

As the relationship was created as part of the `Company_Contact_Relation__c` the relationship name will default to `Contacts__r` (as hinted at in the error message).

So try:

```
(select id , firstname from contacts__r)
```

instead of:

```
(select id , firstname from contact)
```

If that doesn't work you can go to the Setup UI and check the relationship name and use the name you find (and include the `__r`).

Take a look at [A Deeper look at SOQL and Relationship Queries on Force.com](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com)
 for more detail about the naming including examples.